# Electron upload local files to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, electron, firebase-storage, fs

I am writing an electron app with firebase as my backend. I am trying to create a backup-like/storage application where the user can chose a folder, and the entire folder is recursively stored in firebase storage. I have the user chose a path using the electron dialog, but firebase requires a blob or a file to upload something, and I only have the `file://` url. I know that one solution would be to use a file input, but I need to use the dialog path-choosing system. I have tried searching for ways to convert buffers from `fs` into a blob or file type, but nothing I found was a clean solution. I know people have faced this problem when making react-native apps, but they use custom libraries that I have not found for nodejs. I also looked into using `@google-cloud/storage` but the documentation for NodeJS is not very clear, and I couldn't find a way to monitor progress. If anyone knows a way to do this, I really appreciate the help, and if it is not possible to do this, any help on different methods is appreciated too. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why aren't you storing data in [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage), as that's what it's for.

Comment: @Jay Thank you for the response, but my problem is that I cannot upload to Firebase Storage without a Blob or File unless I use some weird workarounds.

Comment: Not sure what that means. Firebase Storage supports LOTS of file types and does not require a blob at all. Storage doesn't really care what you upload to it and since you're uploading the contents of a folder, those would files, right? A folder contains files or other folders?

Comment: Yes, but my problem is getting a format the storage.upload accepts, because I only have the `file://` url to the path on the local machine, and not a description of the data. Only the admin sdk and @google-cloud/storage work like this, and I can't use the admin sdk on a user-facing app, and the google-cloud/storage module doesn't give progress reports or use file recursion for uploading.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. From what I gather, you want to store the contents of your folder in storage. *file://* is the parameter that tells us what it is, like *ftp://* or *http://* but isn't directly related to what you are trying to do. The important bit is what's following the *file://*. So an example (macOS) is *file:///Users/someUser/Desktop/My Document.txt* and the last path component is the file you want to upload. In Swift we would say `let fileName = url.lastPathComponent` and fileName would then be *My Document.txt* which is what you would upload.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but whenever I try to upload a path or url, firebase storage throws an error saying that it requires a file, blob, or byte array. I need to find a way to create a file or blob from the file path, which I would probably have to do from main.js in my electron app.

Comment: You can't upload a *path*, and that doesn't really make any sense in this context as a path is a representation of *where a file is located* - it's not the file itself. You need to upload the actual file